# Syntax to cancel optional timer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I am trying to stop a timer using the following code;

```
//how initiated
 var waitingForResponseTimer : Timer?

//stop
    if let timer = waitingForResponseTimer {
           timer.invalidate
    }
```

The compiler is giving me an error 'Expression Resolves to an Unused Function

What is the proper syntax to cancel the timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need ( `invalidate` is a method not a property )

```
waitingForResponseTimer?.invalidate()
```

if the timer is not nil it will be stopped , otherwise being optional nil?.... will make the line safe , it could be also

```
if let timer = waitingForResponseTimer {
       timer.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked!  Looks like I left off the parentheses. Will accept answer when it allows me (10 minutes)